Failed to build web service client in Netbeans
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/CatalogManager
at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.createEntityResolver(XmlUtil.java:317)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.parseArguments(WsimportOptions.java:333)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.parseArguments(WsimportOptions.java:262)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.parseArguments(WsimportTool.java:379)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:202)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:183)
at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImportBase.runInVm(WsImportBase.java:599)
at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsTask2.execute(WsTask2.java:487)
at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImportBase.execute(WsImportBase.java:582)
at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport2.execute(WsImport2.java:53)
at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:103)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
at
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
Why I always pop out the error while try to create a web service client
Please help me to debugging

Does this answer your question? java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager Java 11

but where to find pom.xml, because i using glassfish and can't find pom.xml. I only found build.xml or catalog.xml
